# How to dialyze large amounts of precipitated enzyme solution (ammonium sulfate)?

Tags: enzymes, purification

I am no biochemist, but I want to purify some liters of solution through dialysis. What I know are those dialysis tubes in glas vessels on stir plates for labs. But how is this done in industry for bigger quantities in an affordable way?
Background: The solution contains a precipitated enzyme (183 kDa) with ammonium sulfate (132 Da). I want to take away the ammonium sulfate to get back the active state of the enzyme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ammonium Sulfate (AS) precipitation is used to concentrate protein. After AS precipitation, you would centrifuge the sample to pellet the protein and then resuspend it in a small volume of water or buffer. You can then dialyze this small volume.

There are other methods of concentrating large volumes of protein, including chromatography and ultrafiltration.